# powershell convert array of hastables into csv

Tags: powershell

Have done googling but have not found suitable answer

I have

```
     $a = @(
           @{"name"="a"; "value"="1"},
           @{"name"="b"; "value"="2"}
       )

    Foreach($x in $a){
          $obj = New-object psobject
          Foreach($key in $x.keys) {
                 $obj ¦ add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name $key -value $x[$key]
           }
           $obj ¦ export-cvs test.csv
     }
```

I get only last line in cab. I want all the lines

Comment: You can´t add an element with the same name two times to a PSObject. You can use a custom table

Answer (score 3):

It's truth that Export-Csv won't append (< v3), but I do not think ConvertTo-Csv will solve the problem... In the end you will get file with headers repeated for every object in your array. I would suggest one of two things:

- move Export-Csv outside foreach {} (need to put it in subexpression though, because it won't be possible to pipe it by default)
- use Foreach-Object instead and get same results

I would also suggest to use New-Object PSObject -Property parameter instead of adding members later: because you use hashtable as a base you are half way there, see attached code samples:

```
# Using $( foreach ($x in $a) {} ) | Export-Csv
$(Foreach($x in $a){
    New-object psobject -Property $x
}) | Export-Csv test.csv

# Using $a | Foreach-Object {} | Export-Csv
$a | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Object PSObject -Property $_ 
} | Export-Csv test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

2022 update

1. You always need to use the -append parameter if you are iterating through a collection
2. using powershell 7.2 and later you don`t need to parse the hashtable again, it matches the repeating properties and writes to csv.

so this will work automatically

```
$hashtable=@()
$hashtable += $pscustomobject

$hashtable | export-csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the csv file each time.  Try using convertTo-CSV each time (instead of export-csv) and appending that to a file.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how to append? I did get-help on both export-csv and converted- csv but did not see append?

Comment: BartekB makes a good point about the headers.   With this approach you won't get what you want, because the output of each convertto-csv call will have its own header.  BartekB's solution, using the hashtables to create custom objects and using export-csv on the set of those is a better solution.  And for completeness' sake, I intended you to use set-content with the -append switch to do the output.  I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

When working with older powershells, I made this simplified version. It's not the quickest, but it'll actually leverage the ConvertTo-Csv functionality for array AND hashtable support

```
Function ConvertTo-CsvList([Parameter(Position = 0)][array]$in, $Delimiter) {
  $csva = ConvertTo-Csv ([PSCustomObject]($in | Select-Object -First 1)) -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $Delimiter
  $csva += $in | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { @(ConvertTo-Csv ([PSCustomObject]$_) -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $Delimiter)[1] }
  $csva -join "`n"
}
```

What it does is, convert the first hashtable to CSV with header: For this it uses the solution from [Export hashtable to csv from keys to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363870/export-hashtable-to-csv-from-keys-to-value).

Then append all the other items headerless to the string-array: As -NoHeader is not available in all versions, the 2-entry string array result is taken, for which the 2nd entry is the datarow.

Finally join it together as one complete csv-string ready for export or whatever is to be done with it.