# Export hashtable to csv from keys to value

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Ok, I'm struggling with this one. I need to export this hash table to a csv.

```
$Sku = @{
        "AAD_BASIC"                              = "Azure Active Directory Basic"
        "RMS_S_ENTERPRISE"                       = "Azure Active Directory Rights Management"
        "AAD_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Active Directory Premium P1"
        "AAD_PREMIUM_P2"                         = "Azure Active Directory Premium P2"
        "MFA_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Multi-Factor Authentication"
        "RIGHTSMANAGEMENT"                       = "Azure Information Protcetion Plan 1"
        "O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS"               = "Office 365 Business Essentials"
        "O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM"                  = "Office 365 Business Premium"
        "ADALLOM_O365"                           = "Office 365 Cloud App Security"
        "ADALLOM_S_DISCOVERY"                    = "Unknown"
```

The above is a sample of the hash table You can find the site here: https://github.com/directorcia/Office365/blob/master/o365-skus.ps1

When I export it turns into a mess. I tried to convert it to a pscustom object. Because of how the table is setup, I have to call the basic . item. Is there a way to reference the .item instead of calling out each item. I've tried .name and .value, neither of them has worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A hash table can easily be converted into a PSCustomObject directly. PSCustomObject can be directly exported/converted to CSV.

```
$Sku = @{
        "AAD_BASIC"                              = "Azure Active Directory Basic"
        "RMS_S_ENTERPRISE"                       = "Azure Active Directory Rights Management"
        "AAD_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Active Directory Premium P1"
        "AAD_PREMIUM_P2"                         = "Azure Active Directory Premium P2"
        "MFA_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Multi-Factor Authentication"
        "RIGHTSMANAGEMENT"                       = "Azure Information Protcetion Plan 1"
        "O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS"               = "Office 365 Business Essentials"
        "O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM"                  = "Office 365 Business Premium"
        "ADALLOM_O365"                           = "Office 365 Cloud App Security"
        "ADALLOM_S_DISCOVERY"                    = "Unknown"
}

[PSCustomObject]$sku | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**EDIT**

As of powershell [v7.2.0-preview.9](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.2.0-preview.9), you can pass the hash table directly to the CSV cmdlets

```
$Sku = @{
        "AAD_BASIC"                              = "Azure Active Directory Basic"
        "RMS_S_ENTERPRISE"                       = "Azure Active Directory Rights Management"
        "AAD_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Active Directory Premium P1"
        "AAD_PREMIUM_P2"                         = "Azure Active Directory Premium P2"
        "MFA_PREMIUM"                            = "Azure Multi-Factor Authentication"
        "RIGHTSMANAGEMENT"                       = "Azure Information Protcetion Plan 1"
        "O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS"               = "Office 365 Business Essentials"
        "O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM"                  = "Office 365 Business Premium"
        "ADALLOM_O365"                           = "Office 365 Cloud App Security"
        "ADALLOM_S_DISCOVERY"                    = "Unknown"
}

$sku | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Also note, -NoTypeInformation is now the default, it's only needed in Windows Powershell.

Comment: Nicely done. Note that it would be nice if hash tables worked _directly_ with `ConvertTo-Csv` - see [GitHub feature request #10999](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10999).

Comment: Amazing response. Thank you! I have converted this list to a csv file and sent it to the people that needed it. It's funny because it was staring me in the face. Sometimes it's hard to see the forest because of all the trees.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 - I hadn't seen that request yet so now it has an extra up vote. Looks like it's already going to be added?

Comment: Well, there's a [PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11029) awaiting review, but it's been in that state for a while. Fingers crossed.